# A combustion engine uses cylinders to compress air and fuel before igniting it

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, physical-chemistry, combustion

The piston moves up to compress the mixture before exploding and sending the piston down with great force.

Would there be any improvement if the piston were turned upside-down? This would mean the piston uses the force of gravity to compress the mixture before exploding.

Comment: Automobile engines have a variety of configurations. Not all of them have the piston moving up to compress (although for changing spark plugs that is more convenient). But, compare the force needed to get a compression ratio of ~10 or so to the force of gravity.

Comment: The force of gravity would be negligible compared to the required compression pressure. In any case, it would require elevating the crankshaft.

Comment: Suppose a 1 cylinder engine, with no [crankshaft counterweight](https://isavetractors.com/articles-1/engine-science-the-balancing-act-of-single-cylinder-engines/). It would convert a tiny amount of gravitational potential energy (PE) to kinetic energy (KE) each time the piston went down, but then it would convert an equal amount of KE back to PE each time the piston rose back up, so there would be no net gain. In reality, engines are balanced with counterweights, and often with multiple pistons always moving in opposite directions, in order to minimize vibration.

Comment: That would require the combustion pressure to push against gravity to raise the piston, so it may even decrease your power output in a large engine.

Answer (score 2):

No, for two reasons:

1. Any gain you get by having gravity help the piston go down is consumed by having the piston go back up again.
2. Even if that were not true, the difference in gravitational potential energy between the top and bottom of a stroke is miniscule compared to the energy release in the combustion chamber when the mixture ignites.